# React Beautiful DND not working, element not being dragged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, drag-and-drop

Been trying to apply a transfer list to hide or show table columns.
followed the official React Beautiful DND tuturial, but it just simply does not work.

Cloned a project using the same versions that i use, and it works.
Copy'd the files that work to my project, and still does not work.
Some other posts about this issue, mentioned the ref, but that does not work also.

using
"react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
"next": "13.2.4",

same versions that on cloned project.

Files:

DndContext.tsx

```
"use client";

import { DragDropContext, DropResult } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';


export const DndContext = ({ children, onDragEnd }: {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    onDragEnd: (result: DropResult) => void
}) => {

    return <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        {children}
    </DragDropContext>
}
```

DndExample.tsx

```
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Draggable, DropResult, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import LoadingSkeleton from "./LoadingSkeleton";
import { DndContext } from "../context/DndContext";
interface Cards {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    components: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }[];
}
const DndExample = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Cards[] | []>([])
    const onDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
        const { source, destination } = result;
        if (!destination) return;
        if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
            const newData = [...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))];//shallow copy concept
            const oldDroppableIndex = newData.findIndex(x => x.id == source.droppableId.split("droppable")[1]);
            const newDroppableIndex = newData.findIndex(x => x.id == destination.droppableId.split("droppable")[1])
            const [item] = newData[oldDroppableIndex].components.splice(source.index, 1);
            newData[newDroppableIndex].components.splice(destination.index, 0, item);
            setData([...newData]);
        } else {
            const newData = [...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))];//shallow copy concept
            const droppableIndex = newData.findIndex(x => x.id == source.droppableId.split("droppable")[1]);
            const [item] = newData[droppableIndex].components.splice(source.index, 1);
            newData[droppableIndex].components.splice(destination.index, 0, item);
            setData([...newData]);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        setData([
            {
              id: 0,
              title: "Component Librarys",
              components: [
                {
                  id: 100,
                  name: "material ui"
                },
                {
                  id: 200,
                  name: "bootstrap"
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              title: "Javascript Librarys",
              components: [
                {
                  id: 300,
                  name: "react"
                },
                {
                  id: 400,
                  name: "node"
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              title: "react helping Librarys",
              components: [
                {
                  id: 500,
                  name: "redux"
                },
                {
                  id: 600,
                  name: "recoil"
                },
              ]
            }
          
          
          ])
    }, [])
    if (!data.length) {
        return <LoadingSkeleton />
    }
    return (
        <DndContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
            <h1 className="text-center mt-8 mb-3 font-bold text-[25px] ">Drag and Drop Application</h1>
            <div className="flex gap-4 justify-between my-20 mx-4 flex-col lg:flex-row">
                {
                    data.map((val, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Droppable key={index} droppableId={`droppable${index}`}>
                                {
                                    (provided) => (
                                        <div className="p-5 lg:w-1/3 w-full bg-white  border-gray-400 border border-dashed"
                                            {...provided.droppableProps}
                                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                                        >
                                            <h2 className="text-center font-bold mb-6 text-black">{val.title}</h2>
                                            {
                                                val.components?.map((component, index) => (
                                                    <Draggable key={component.id} draggableId={component.id.toString()} index={index}>
                                                        {
                                                            (provided) => (
                                                                <div className="bg-gray-200 mx-1 px-4 py-3 my-3"
                                                                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                                >{component.name}</div>
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    </Draggable>
                                                ))
                                            }
                                            {provided.placeholder}
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                }

                            </Droppable>
                        )
                    })
                }


            </div>
        </DndContext>
    )
};

export default DndExample;
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: What doesn't work is the element drag, it does show the cursor, but there is no element drag.
Still dont know what is wrong, but since then, i am using dnd-kit and works properly.
Thank you for the reply.